# Does WITH create a temporary table and if so can it be used in multiple threads safely?

Tags: sql, multithreading, postgresql, with-statement

In Postgres, is a `WITH` clause creating a temporary table and if so can it be used in multiple threads safely ?

I.e. WITH x below, would this be ok if the CTE running in multiple different threads?

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT  psp_id
   FROM    global.prospect
   WHERE   status IN ('new', 'reset')
   ORDER   BY request_ts
   LIMIT   1
   )
UPDATE global.prospect psp
SET    status = status || '*'
FROM   x
WHERE  psp.psp_id = x.psp_id
RETURNING psp.*;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

A query with a CTE creates an internal, temporary representation of a table that is visible exclusively to the query itself.

I don't see a way to use a `TEMPORARY` table in multiple threads either, since temporary tables are only visible within the same session.

The next best thing would be an [**`UNLOGGED`** table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html). Still cheaper than a regular table, but not quite as cheap as either of the above.

Unlike with a CTE, you can create indexes and `ANALYZE` `TEMPORARY` or `UNLOGGED` tables, though - which may help *a lot* with huge cardinalities but not with your example (`LIMIT 1`).

Comment: I am not sure, but CTE doesn't create a TEMPORARY TABLE ever. It is much more similar to derived tables e.g. So you can use CTE without any risk related to identifier collisions from more parallel processes, because no table is created.

Comment: @PavelStehule: I didn't mean an actual `TEMPORARY` table, just a table that is temporary. The different formatting should convey that message. I don't actually know how the "common table" is implemented exactly.

Comment: It is hard to talk about CTE as table - resp. it is abstraction (and then a name "relation" is better, because all tables are relations, but not all relations are tables - some relations has not physical representation). Internally it is something what produce rows when executor requests it.

Comment: @PavelStehule: Well, CTE stands for Common *Table* Expression, so the term shouldn't be completely misplaced. I changed it to read "representation of a table" now. These comments help to clarify, if there should be any doubt.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: thanks for the answer but I am a bit confused. So I cannot use CTE in multiple thread as the name 'x' in my example is the same in multiple threads?

Comment: @Gob00st: With standard PostgreSQL you cannot. I don't know of any way to do that and don't think there is one.

Comment: @Gob00st: Use an unlogged table I suggested in my answer?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: But I don't see how UNlogged table would help me in multi-thread environment ?

Comment: @Gob00st: It is the cheapest method to save a temporary table that must be visible in multiple threads (sessions).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: But I don't want this 'tem table' to be visible for multiple thread to avoid the potential conflict.

Comment: @Gob00st: I must have misunderstood your intentions. I thought you *want* to share the results of a computationally expensive subquery in multiple threads. If you are just worried about naming conflicts: CTEs are *only* visible inside the same query. Never across multiple queries, let alone sessions or threads.